# I am getting an Invalid syntax while applying filter to my Spark Context (sc)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting an invalid syntax error when running code in pyspark Python 3 notebook, looks like the original code I am studying and practising with is in scala and syntax is slightly different ...
the issue appears to be related to the '=>' operator but cant seem to figure out the correct one to use as I am still new to this language

```
for i in range(1980, 2016):
    print(i)
    yearStats = sc.textFile("./BasketballStats-master.zip\BasketballStats-master\data\leagues_NBA_$i*")
    yearStats.filter(x => x.contains(",")).map(x =>  (i,x)).saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats\$i")
```

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-40-22cd8339dbdd>", line 4
    yearStats.filter(x => x.contains(",")).map(x =>  (i,x)).saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats\$i")
                        
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

you are mixing the syntax of `Scala` and `Python`.  You have written `For Loop` in `Python` and rest of code in `Scala`.

**Python Code**

```
for i in range(1980, 2016):
    print(i)
    yearStats = sc.textFile("./BasketballStats-master.zip\BasketballStats-master\data\leagues_NBA_$i*")
    yearStats.filter(lambda x : x.contains(",")).map( lambda x:  (i,x)).saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats")
```

**Scala Code**

```
for (i <- 1980 to 2016){
    prinln(i)
    yearStats = sc.textFile("./BasketballStats-master.zip\BasketballStats-master\data\leagues_NBA_$i*")
    yearStats.filter(x => x.contains(",")).map(x =>  (i,x)).saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shanka/Gaurang, I had actually used the lambda function as you have suggested  during one of my attempts and it  threw an error at the 'year stats' filter:     Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-005eace04ec9> in <module>
      2     print(i)
      3     yearStats = sc.textFile("./BasketballStats-master.zip\BasketballStats-master\data\leagues_NBA_$i*")
----> 4     yearStats.filter(lambda x : x.contains(",")).map( lambda x:  (i,x)).saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats\$i")

Comment: looks like error is being caused by the last part of the chain: .saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats\$i") ... i removed and was able to get the full range of dates ... however that data still needs to be saved :) .... soooo .... for the life of me cant seem to see what the error is with the '.saveAsTextFile("./BasketballStats\$i")'